# Ruby Hashes: getting a set of keys from sorted values

Tags: ruby, hash

Hi all I've made myself quite a complicated (at least, for me) construction.
I have a Hash, looking like (example):

```
states_with_depths = {
 #State => depth
 "S0" => 0,
 "S1" => 1,
 "S2" => 2,
 "S3" => 2,
 "S4" => 2,
 "S5" => 3
}
```

(note: its a Hash, so its not sorted yet)

Now what I would like:
Having a loop starting at depth = 0 with a set of all states having depth 0 or less,
next iteration of the loop, having a set of all states with depth 1 or less, etc.

What would be a neat way to get such a construction?

Please let me know if my question is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `group_by` with the value:

```
>> states_with_depths.group_by { |k,v| v }
 #=> {0=>[["S0", 0]], 1=>[["S1", 1]], 2=>[["S2", 2], ["S3", 2], ["S4", 2]], 3=>[["S5", 3]]}
```

This can also be shortened to:

```
states_with_depths.group_by(&:last)
```

To use this you can do something like:

```
states_with_depths.group_by(&:last).each do |depth, arrs| 
  puts "Values with depth #{depth}: #{arrs.map(&:first)}"                                                                                                                        
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Values with depth 0: ["S0"]
Values with depth 1: ["S1"]
Values with depth 2: ["S2", "S3", "S4"]
Values with depth 3: ["S5"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested it, and it works great! I'm sticking with the solution of J-.-L, because its result is closer to what i needed

Comment: note: i was not able to edit your comment, but there is an extra "}" after `(&:first)}"`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I rewrote it from a `{}` block do a `do...end` one because it's easier to read here and then forgot that one curly brace.

Comment: BTW: This `states_with_depths.group_by(&:last).map { |d, arr| arr.map(&:first) }` should also provide what you need. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'set'

depths_with_states = []

max_level = states_with_depths.max_by{|e|e[1]}[1]

states_with_depths.map{ |state, level|
  (level..max_level).each{ |i|
    depths_with_states[i] ||= Set.new  # ...or just array
    depths_with_states[i] << state
  }
}

depths_with_states.each{ |states|
  # do whatever you want to do ;)
}
```

Comment: There is an error in the code:
doing `(0..level).each { |i| ..` causes the depths_with_states[i] having the set of all states with depth i+ instead of 0..i

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation that works for Ruby before 1.8.7 (when `Enumerable#group_by` was added):

```
states_by_depth = Hash.new{|h,depth| h[depth]=[] }
states_with_depths.each{ |state,depth| states_by_depth[depth] << state }
#=> {0=>["S0"], 1=>["S1"], 2=>["S3", "S4", "S2"], 3=>["S5"]}
min_depth = states_by_depth.keys.min
max_depth = states_by_depth.keys.max
min_depth.upto(max_depth) do |depth|
  next unless states = states_by_depth[depth]
  puts "Depth: #{depth}"
  states.each{ |state| puts "..#{state}" }
end
#=> Depth: 0
#=> ..S0
#=> Depth: 1
#=> ..S1
#=> Depth: 2
#=> ..S3
#=> ..S4
#=> ..S2
#=> Depth: 3
#=> ..S5
```